# Why Apps for Office options is disabled in my outlook 2013 instance

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I have developed a Mail app for outlook I want it to be available for outlook desktop but I can't see the "App for office" option enabled in on outlook desktop client.
[image]

I have checked with my outlook version it is up to date but don't know whats going wrong. Anyone can help in this, would be much appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Is your Outlook configured to connect to an Exchange or Office 365 mailbox?

Comment: Yes it is configured to connect to an office 365 account mailbox.

Comment: Finally I got success I just remove the outlook profile & recreate the same profile and restart outlook, after that it started showing Apps for office option also my Taskpane Addin is visible in a app dialog.

Comment: Ah ok. There must have been something corrupted in your profile. You might want to add that as an answer to your question so other folks can benefit :)

Comment: Yes you are right it was failing due to some pre-installed COM add-in. I have to remove all those add-in than restart outlook after profile recreation.

Answer (score 0):

After spending few hours I just give few trial by removing some COM add-in & profile re creation, perhaps some COM add-in causing the issue.
So anyone can try with following to overcome such behavior of Outlook Desktop:

1. Remove any COM add-in which you have developed & debugging with
   outlook desktop client.
2. If problem persists than you can try delete profile & create again.

Go to control panel > Mail > Click on Show profile button, than delete exists profile & add again with followed wizard.